# How to remove duplicates and get the greatest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a SQL statement that will select the highest id but only the top value if duplicates exist.

**id - value**

- 1491825 - 3339
- 1491824 - 3170
- 1491823 - 3143
- 1491822 - 3422
- 1491821 - 3422
- 1491820 - 3422
- 1491819 - 3422
- 1491818 - 3422
- 1491817 - 3261
- 1491816 - 3170
- 1491815 - 3170
- 1491814 - 3170
- 1491813 - 3170
- 1491812 - 3170
- 1491811 - 3170
- 1491810 - 3170
- 1491809 - 3170
- 1491808 - 3170
- 1491807 - 3251
- 1491806 - 3422

**Expected Output**:

**id - value**

- 1491825 - 3339
- 1491824 - 3170
- 1491823 - 3143
- 1491822 - 3422
- 1491817 - 3261
- 1491807 - 3251

Comment: select distinct(column-name) from (table-name) order by (column-name) asc

Comment: @AurA I think you might have misunderstood the Question a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select max(id),value From foo
group by value
order by max(id) desc
```

See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ee34/3

*Edit. Darn. Beaten to it by astander.*

Comment: your order by max(id) desc seperated the 2 statements as well as the sqlfiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
SELECT  MAX(id) as id
        value
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY value
```

Answer (score -1):

The MAX() function is true and best answer